# How do I iterate over a pandas dataframe to impute missing values that are present in another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to impute the NaN's in a column with the values present in same column but I cannot figure out how to map them using another column.

I have two pandas DataFrames, the first one(df) has all the values and looks like this:

```
|Sr. No| Fares|   Route    |
|------|------|------------|
|  1   | 123  |ABE-PGD-ABE |
|  2   | 456  |ABQ-SLC-ABQ |
|  3   | 789  |ALB-SJU-ALB |
```

The second DataFrame(df1) looks like this:

```
|Sr. No| Fares|   Route    |
|------|------|------------|
|  130 | NaN  |ABE-PGD-ABE |
|  297 | NaN  |ABQ-SLC-ABQ |
|  345 | NaN  |ALB-SJU-ALB |
```

Now I want to impute the NaN in the Fares column for all the Routes that match. Also the second DataFrame is just a subset of the first one because I wanted to isolate all the NaNs in the Fare column.

Here is my code:

```py
for i in df_1: 
     df[Fare] = df[Fare].map({'Nan': ''})
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, I don't know what to map it with so I have left the value for 'Nan' blank.

Comment: I apologize for my poor formatting and bad framing, I am still new to it. Thanks

Comment: No images please, review the guidelines here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you trying to use `df_round` to populate the `NaN` values in `df_null`? So something like `if ITIN_FARE is NaN in df_null, and route is found in df_round, then populate df_null[ITIN_FARE] using df[ITIN_FARE] for the matching route`. It's not entirely clear; the example image you show doesn't have any matching routes.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do! I apologize for the example image, I removed it and just added the tables to make it simpler and adhere to the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going on here.

Firstly, when you iterate a DataFrame like `for i in df`, you are actually iterating the columns (or Series), not the rows as you might expect. You can access a row iterator by `df.iterrows()`, which looks like

```
for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
    # row is a pd.Series, which is like a vector / array / tuple
```

Within the loop you need to "pull out" the `route`, then use that `route` to "look up" the fare in the other DataFrame.

```
for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
    route = row["Route"]

    # find other rows that match this Route
    other_rows = df_other[df_other["Route"]==route]

    # if there isn"t exactly only one row, skip
    if len(other_rows) != 1:
        continue

    # this is how we can set a value in a dataframe
    df.loc[row_index, "Fares"] = other_rows.iloc[0]["fares"]
```

Having said all this, we wouldn't normally treat a DataFrame as a list of rows to iterate. Think of it as a database table and try for set-based operations.

Here's how I would do this:

```
# index these so we can compare corresponding rows
df = df.set_index("Route")
df_other = df_other.set_index("Route")

# combine first performs a "if null" kind of coalescing
combined = df.combine_first(df_other)

# the index ensures that we are updating rows correctly
df["Fares"] = combined["Fares"]
```